# How to query OMDb with genre and year?

Tags: json, api, imdb

I am using the [OMDb api](http://www.omdbapi.com/), I am able to search only with respect to IMDb  ID or Title like [Search for title with Game and released in the year 2014](http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game&y=2014&plot=full&r=json).

But I want to search with out the title for example the action movies released in 2014, it will be good for me if the result contains all instead of showing only 9 results.

If not possible via OMDb api, refer some other API which can do the same.

Comment: the omdbapi documentation states that you must search by either title or IMDB id, you will need to find a different API or library to search imdb api instead,although omdbapi.com does offer a regular dump of information that you might be able to manipulate (unsure how large it is)